# Get title from textfield then use to display function

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, textbox, title

I asked this question previously although I don't think I did a great job of explaining it and the answers didn't seem to work so this is my second attempt. FYI, I'm using Wordpress.

I wish to create an image slideshow plugin. The idea is that the user can enter the name of the slideshow into a text field then submit it which will use Wordpress's 'add_option' function to add it to the database.

Then, this name will be used to display that specific slideshow and contain its own individual settings. It will also create a submenu page on wordpress titled the name the user has given it.

The user can then display this specific slideshow via PHP.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your issue/problem or having trouble with? What you describe can be done with wordpress hooks and filters...

Comment: I don't have a clue how to do it. That's what I am asking; how can this be achieved?

Comment: Original Question Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430303/define-function-name-with-text-field/3430911#3430911

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  Have you written a plug-in before?